# ANDROID: The website doesn't load properly and some links doesn't work in webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

When I check my webpage using google chrome in my android based cellphone,the webpage loads completely and everything works fine, however when I load the same webpage in Webview the website doesn't load properly, specially the jquery content. 
Also none of my links does work in webview. some of the links are simple a href links and some others use javascript.

This is my code to load webpage:

```
webView.postUrl("http://www.url.com/users/login", EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Whats wrong with the webview?

I have to post some data to web page, so I could not use the external web browser (they doesn't support post action)

By the way, I get this in my logcat when I touch a link:

```
E/webcoreglue﹕ Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you have the internet permission in your manifest ?

Comment: Yes, how could it load the web page without internet access!!! It loads the webpage but I can't load it properly.

Comment: Yes Taher i also facing this Issue in my Android App but not able to get the Reason and solution for that . And I also added the Internet Permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the browser: hold home and swipe the browser to completely close it. Haven't found a way to fix this permanently though.